# Resumir dados em Excel sem VBA ou tabela dinâmica

Tags: microsoft-excel

Desculpem se esta questão já foi respondida, mas não estou conseguindo nem elaborar a pergunta para fazer a pesquisa adequada.

Tenho uma lista de produtos vendidos no excel, e preciso selecionar os três produtos mais vendidos da lista. Até ai, poderia utilizar a função "Maior". O problema, é que os produtos podem se repetir na lista, eu não tenho espaço para criar tabelas dinâmicas, ou utilizar VBA na planilha.

Segue um exemplo dos dados:

```
    Produto | Vendido | QTT
    P1      |  1073,79|   21
    P2      |   553,72|   25
    P3      |   748,94|    6
    P4      |  1017,97|   13
    P1      |    98,98|    4
    P2      |   173,71|    9
    P3      |   189,98|    2
    P5      |   250,97|    3
```

Precisava colocar em uma coluna, na mesma planilha, os produtos P1, P4 e P3, com os respectivos valores.

Isso é possível?

Comment: Coloque um exemplo de como deverá ficar esta sua planilha.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize um `somases` para somar todos os valores vendidos de determinado produto.

https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/SOMASES-Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-SOMASES-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b

```
=SOMASES(B2:B9;A2:A9;"P1")
```

Onde o intervalo `B2:B9`são os valores que devem ser somados, o intervalo `A2:A9`o intervalo de comparação (produtos) e o último parâmetro o que deve ser comparado `P1` (PRODUTO 1).